# Reduce plot width so the legend will not be truncated

Tags: r, plot

I draw the legend outsidte the plot area. When rendering, the right part of the legend is truncated. How can i reduce the plot width, so it will fit?

[image: R plot with truncated legend]

```
# resultValues got 9 cols and 2 rows, colors is a vector with 9 colors
# The maximal y value is 2400
# Setting width to a higher value just streches everthing
pdf("Lineplot.pdf", width = 10, height = 6)
max_y <- max(resultValues)
plot(resultValues$col1, type="o", col=colors[1], ylim=c(0,max_y), axes=FALSE,
     ann=FALSE, lwd=1.5)
axis(1, at=1:2, lab=c("2013", "2014"))
axis(2, las=1, at=250*0:max_y)
for (colname in colnames) {
  lines(resultValues[[colname]], type="o", lwd=1.5,
        col=colors[match(colname, names(resultValues))])
}
box()
par(xpd=TRUE, mar=par()$mar+c(0,0,0,6))
legend(2.05, 2500, legend=names(resultValues), ncol=1, cex=1, fill=colors,
       xjust=0, xpd=TRUE)
dev.off()
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
```

Comment: Did you try altering the `par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)` ? I would hope that the margins would resolve the problem.

Comment: I did, but unfortunately after the `plot()` call. Like @bgoldst said, it must be done _before_ it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem by configuring a wider right margin using `par(mar=...)`. Note that this must be done *prior* to the main `plot()` call, because margins cannot be changed after they are fixed by the initial `plot()` call.

Demo (using synthesized data, as you didn't provide `resultValues` or `colors`) (assumes you've already set up your graphics device, e.g. `pdf()`, `x11()`, whatever):

```
## store data
resultValues <- data.frame(col1=c(40,70),col2=c(1710,2500),col3=c(580,280),col4=c(200,1050),col5=c(160,140),col6=c(260,10),col7=c(380,300),col8=c(380,600),col9=c(150,190));
colors <- c('red','orange','lightgreen','green','#00ff88','#0088ff','blue','purple','magenta');
colnames <- colnames(resultValues);

## widen right margin
par(mar=par('mar')+c(0,0,0,3));

## draw plot
max_y <- max(resultValues);
plot(resultValues$col1, type="o", col=colors[1], ylim=c(0,max_y), axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE, lwd=1.5);
axis(1, at=1:2, lab=c("2013", "2014"));
axis(2, las=1, at=250*0:max_y);
for (colname in colnames) lines(resultValues[[colname]], type="o", lwd=1.5, col=colors[match(colname, names(resultValues))]);
box();
legend(2.05, 2500, legend=names(resultValues), ncol=1, cex=1, fill=colors, xjust=0, xpd=TRUE);
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Works fine, my problem was that i had set the margins _after_ the main plot call and not _before_ it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ggplot2.

```
resultValues <- data.frame(col1=c(40,70),col2=c(1710,2500),col3=c(580,280),col4=c(200,1050),col5=c(160,140),col6=c(260,10),col7=c(380,300),col8=c(380,600),col9=c(150,190))
# ^ borrowed from above :)

resultValues = rbind(t(resultValues[1,]),t(resultValues[2,]) )
resultValues = data.frame(resultValues)
resultValues$col = c(paste("col", 1:9, sep = "") , paste("col", 1:9, sep = ""))
resultValues$year = c(rep("2013",nrow(resultValues)/2),rep("2014",nrow(resultValues)/2))
names(resultValues) = c("y_value","col","year")
```

Plotting:

```
require("ggplot2")

  ggplot( resultValues, aes(x = year, y = y_value, group = col) ) +
          geom_point(aes(color = col), size = 3.5,shape =1) +
          geom_line(aes(color = col)) +
          scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.05,0.05)) +
          xlab("Year") +
          ylab("") +
          ggtitle( "Your Graph" ) +
          theme_bw() + 
          theme(   panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
                 , panel.grid.major = element_blank()
                 , legend.title=element_blank()
                 )
```

[image]